# Variadic Templates and Vertex Buffer Attributes

Tags: c++, templates, opengl, variadic-templates, vbo

In OpenGL, when creating a VBO, one must do all 3 of these things:

- Create the buffer

```cpp
unsigned int vboId;
glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

- Ensure the the buffer is bound

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
```

- Enable and define the attributes

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Doing this in raw OpenGL, although simple, can get out of hand if there are many attributes to set for a single buffer. I was thinking that I could simplify the process of calling the attribute functions using variadic templates with an API like this:

```cpp
// 3 float position, 2 float uv texture coord.
float data[] {
    0.f, 0.f, 0.f,   0.f, 0.f,
    0.f, 1.f, 0.f,   0.f, 1.f,
    1.f, 0.f, 0.f,   1.f, 0.f,
    1.f, 1.f, 0.f,   1.f, 1.f,
};
auto vboId = createVbo(data, sizeof(data));
bindVbo(vboId);
setVboLayout<float, 3, float, 2>(vboId);
```

However, this is not doable because the template parameters (AFAIK) can not actually be variadic, and instead can only make parameters variadic. The reason why I don't want to use function parameters is because I want to be able to input the C++ keywords `float` and `int`, which cannot be used as parameters. My current solution is to use parameters with an enum that duplicates the basic types, such as `Float32` and `Int32`. I was wondering if it is possible to do something like this using variadic templates

Comment: Mixing non-type template parameters (`3`) and type template parameters (`float`) cannot be done generically. I suggest to create a wrapper to group `float` and `3` and `float` and `2` which seems anyway related. (`setVboLayout<GlAttribute<float, 3>, GlAttribute<float, 2>>(vboId);`).

Comment: @Jarod42, I will try this out because I didn't think of it, but I originally wanted to be able to use the primitive types, as well as able to specify type counts

Comment: @GabeRundlett: "*`setVboLayout<float, 3, float, 2>(vboId);`*" Why do you want this? What is the difference between that and `setVboLayout(GL_FLOAT, 3, GL_FLOAT, 2, vboId);`? Are you planning to do some compile-time checking of these values? And if so, why? Why is it important to use C++ keywords, even though OpenGL *does not use those keywords*; it uses its own defined types like `GLfloat`, `GLuint`, etc. Overall, this just seems to be a pointless idea.

Comment: @GabeRundlett: "*My current solution is to use parameters with an enum that duplicates the basic types*" OpenGL already has such types.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I want to make the API agnostic of OpenGL. Also, I have multiple reasons why I don't want to have the OpenGL headers included in the main source files of a project aside from this though, such as: The OpenGL headers define a multitude of macros (inlcuding the "types" you say they have like GL_FLOAT) that pollute the global namespace. I personally don't like having these all over the place. Either way, Quentin already solved the issue, so it doesn't matter whether or not it is pointless as you say.

Comment: On top of this, I would like to ensure the values of the stride, offset and size are all evaluated at compile time in order to ensure the lack of overhead in the program. I want them to be the C++ keywords because I want it to be API agnostic.

Comment: @GabeRundlett: "*I want to make the API agnostic of OpenGL.*" This is not the right abstraction for doing that. Low-level calls like those represented here should never be directly exposed to the abstraction's code. It should be dealing in more abstract concepts like objects and models. That gives you the freedom to change the nature of the APIs behind the user's back. Vulkan, for example, makes the vertex format part of the pipeline state, so you can't change it independently of the shader. Also compile-time hard coding makes it impossible to have a mesh file specify it's own format.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I think that is a great point, thank you. I will now consider further abstracting the api based on your statement. I will work on how to allow the user to create their own "objects and models" with the api figuring out all the underlying information. I like your point about it models not being able to be loaded at runtime. I may be a bit autistic about ensuring compile time evaluation because I try to make everything I do compile time to mitigate runtime overhead, but you're right that it probably isnt the best option in this case! Again thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very well make variadic template parameter without deducting them from function parameters. You cannot, however, declare the kind of alternating type and value parameters that you wish for (`<float, 3, float, 2>`).

A solution would be to use a composite type to store both informations, and IMO an array type fits well. So you would declare and call as:

```
template <class... Attributes>
void setVboLayout(VboId vboId);

setVboLayout<float[3], float[2]>(vboId);
```

... which would dispatch to secondary templates that can either match the array type through template specialization, or use `std::extent` to retrieve the size.

Sample implementation:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class Attribute>
    struct attributeTag { };

    std::size_t bindAttribute(VboId, attributeTag<float>, std::size_t offset) {
        // glVertexAttribPointer for a float
        return offset + sizeof(float);
    }

    template <std::size_t ArraySize>
    std::size_t bindAttribute(VboId, attributeTag<float[ArraySize]>, std::size_t offset) {
        // glVertexAttribPointer for a float array
        return offset + sizeof(float[ArraySize]);
    }

    // More overloads for variouts attribute types...
}

template <class... Attributes>
void setVboLayout(VboId vboId) {
    std::size_t offset = 0;
    ((offset = detail::bindAttribute(vboId, detail::attributeTag<Attributes>{}, offset)), ...);
}
```

Here the `bindAttribute` overloads each return the offset right after the just-registered attribute.

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jQCq5C3ceArHu0yC)

Comment: Wow, @Quentin, this is amazing. I did not expect such an elegant solution! I do not even understand how this works and will now spend some considerable time trying to figure out how it works given the code you provided. I have never seen that double parenthesis syntax before, what is it called?

EDIT: Because the call to `glVertexAttribPointer(...)` requires a stride parameter, I'm assuming I would need to first pre-calculate the stride with more template expansion, and then pass said stride to the bind attribute call

Comment: @GabeRundlett this is a (somewhat convoluted) fold-expression over the comma operator, the general form is `(<stuff>, ...)`. This executes `offset = detail::bindAttribute(vboId, detail::attributeTag<A>{}, offset)` for each `A` in `Attributes`, in order.

Comment: @GabeRundlett the stride would be calculated once and passed to all futher calls indeed. My OpenGL is a bit rusty so I'll let you handle the proper location for each calculation ;)